# How to relate two (or more) objects through a property (in javascript)?

Tags: javascript, object

Let's say I have these two objects:

```
let person1 = {name: "Charlie", age: 65, childrenNames:["Ruth", "Charlie Jr."] parentNames: ["Dolph", "Grace"]};

let person2 = {name: "Charlie Jr.", age: 34, childrenNames:[] parentNames: ["Charlie", "Grace"]};
```

Now let's say I want to express the fact that person1 is person2's father and, consequently, that person2 is person1's son. That is, the "Charlie Jr" in the person1's `childrenNames` property is person2 and the "Charlie" in the person2's `parentNames` property is person1.

How could I achieve this? I don't see how embedding one object inside the other would solve the problem, but simply replicate it. Is there a way to make a property inside an object a sort of identifier for another object?

Thanks so much!

Comment: How about having another object indicate family relations? `parents`, `siblings`, `offspring` would of course also do, but I guess it depends on your requirements. Also, if you want to keep a circular reference (the object holding a link to his parent that also contains a link to the son), be aware that this couldn't be serialized out of the box. Also you wouldn't be replicating the objects, it would just  be a property holding a reference to the other object

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question properly. It's perfectly normal to have some sort of "id" property to allow objects to refer to each other by a simple string or number. You appear to be already doing this with the `name` property.

Comment: It might be hard figuring out the mother of Charlie Jr. since they are both called `Grace` :)

Answer (score 0):

For example if you want to know if someone is the child of person 1, you can do something like this:

```
person1.childrenNames.forEach((childrenName) => { 

if(childrenName=== person2.name) {
  console.log(person1.name + ' is the parent of + person2.name);
});
```

Also you can do a nested function so you can check if the person if the parent of multiple persons.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on how complicated your scenario would be and what you would like to achieve, but say you add an extra table for `relations`. This table could hold information on the type of relation 2 persons share, and could then be used to look up that data.

For example, if we have 4 persons, from which 2 are parents (Charlie & Grace) and 1 is the son (Charlie Jr), we could form a relation table as below.

We don't need to indicate that Charlie Jr is a son, as he we already know the parents of the child.

```js
const familyDb = {
  persons: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Charlie', age: 68 },
    { id: 2, name: 'Grace', age: 64 },
    { id: 3, name: 'Charlie Jr', age: 34 },
    { id: 4, name: 'Grace', age: 36 }
  ],
  relations: [
    { id: 1, person1: 1, person2: 2, type: 'spouse', from: 1970, till: null },
    { id: 2, person1: 3, person2: 4, type: 'spouse', from: 2010, till: null },
    { id: 3, person1: 1, person2: 3, type: 'parent' },
    { id: 3, person1: 2, person2: 3, type: 'parent' }
  ]
};

function getParents( person ) {
  return familyDb.relations.filter( relation => relation.person2 === person.id && relation.type === 'parent' );
}

function getChildren( person ) {
  return familyDb.relations.filter( relation => relation.person1 === person.id && relation.type === 'parent' );
}


console.log( getParents( familyDb.persons[2] ) );
console.log( getChildren( familyDb.persons[0] ) );
```

So the above code kinda takes a rudimentary approach to this, you have:

- a unique `id` identifying a person (name matching would be hard in your example as Grace is both the mom of Charlie & Charlie Jr)
- a table identifying a relation of some `type` between two persons

After that you just need a way to look up the information from your dataset and you have a way to get started

Comment: @simón if it helped, you can mark this answer as an answer. See what you can do [after you received an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) on the helpdesk pages

Answer (score 0):

Why not add relationship indexes ? combine your people, to 1 people array.
Iterate and add instead of parentNames, parentIndexes. This way, instead of looking for parents or sons by names, you have the index.

Note, to make my example simple, I am only doing parent to son relationship. You can easily add a son to parent relationship using the exact same logic.

Example

```
if (peopleArray[i].parentsIndex.length > 0) {
  // get first parent
  //peopleArray[peopleArray[i].parentsIndex[0]];
}
```

Modify your object.

```js
let peopleArray = [

  {
    name: "Charlie",
    age: 65,
    parentNames: ["Dolph", "Grace"]
  },
  {
    name: "Grace",
    age: 65,
    parentNames: ["Dolph", "Grace"]
  },
  {
    name: "Dolph",
    age: 65,
    parentNames: ["ADSGS", "Grace"]
  }
];
peopleArray = peopleArray.map(callback.bind(null));

function callback(item) {
    item["parentsIndex"] = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < item.parentNames.length; i++) {
    let parentObj = peopleArray.find(x => x.name === item.parentNames[i]);
    if (parentObj !== undefined) {
      item["parentsIndex"].push(peopleArray.indexOf(parentObj));
    }

  }
  return item;
}
console.log(peopleArray);
// use case 
if (peopleArray[0].parentsIndex.length > 0) {
  // get first parent
  //peopleArray[peopleArray[0].parentsIndex[0]];
}
```